# Direct calls from View to ViewModel. Can DataContext be changed on itself?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

Sometimes, i need to do some calls from View to VM. I know, that it is not MVVM style, but still. Should i always re-check DataContext to be my VM (in case it can be changed by re-activation from tombstoning or something like that), or it is enough to store in once?

```
var vm = DataContext as MyViewModel;
if (vm == null) return;
vm.DoSomething();
```

DataContext is set via Mvvm Light Locator

```
DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always is safe, when it's limited to a page. Whether in constructor, Loaded event handler or OnNavigatedTo, you can create objects and never check them again - either the page was kept in memory with all the objects, or the constructor, Loaded and OnNavigatedTo were called again upon re-activating from tombstoning. Problems with tombstoning occur mostly in cases of *one page* relying on the fact, that *other page* created something.

Comment: Thanks, that's the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use that sometimes, like that:

```
private MyViewModel viewModel;
```

When is the page loaded, then add value to that field

```
viewModel = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
```

Than I can use it anytime in my view after it.

I know it is not MVVM, but still ;)

Comment: So that is the question, is it safe enough?